# How to make combination of images responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header which is having 5 menus. Those 5 menus are nothing but images.

First menu image width is bigger. And all other menu image widths are same as shown below screenshot.

[image]

I have coded as following to make as above.

```
<div id="head-section">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"><img src="res/1.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html"><img src="res/Home-n.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://eywaz.com/sit2/MTA-2Website21-02/mta"><img src="res/blog.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="res/Help-n.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="res/Contact_us-n.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS is as follows:

```
#head-section {
    width:800px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:30px;
}

ul li{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:15%;
}

ul li:first-child{
    width:37.5%;
}

ul li a img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Header is looking nice.
But as I decrease the size of browser, the images in the header are not decreasing.
The size of full header remains same.

I did Google, but I am not getting how to resolve it.
Please can any one tell me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a min-width:your_value%; max-width:100%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use -

```
ul li a img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

and for #head-section

```
#head-section { width:100% }
```

while you are putting 100% width to any selector then don't add padding/margin on that div.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `width` on `#head-section` to `max-width`:

```
#head-section {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```